# Redirect html when fill the input sucess

Tags: javascript, html

I am using this form as a connector with my server in order when i put the correct user and password connects with the form of my web and redirects to the ip but when i put a wrong password or a wrong user i dont want to redirect just stay in the same page.

```html
<div class="container"><!-- CONTAINER -->
      <div class="row"><!-- ROW -->
      <div class="col-md-4"></div>
      <div class="col-md-4"><!-- COL 3 -->
        <form class="login" autocomplete="off" method="post" action="http://139.59.200.233:8080/track/Track">
        <h5>SERVIDOR 1</h5>
        <h2 class="title">Acceso a plataforma GPS</h2>
        <input id="accountLoginField" type="hidden" value="occidentegps" name="account" required>
        <input type="text"  name="user" placeholder="Usuario" autofocus required/>
        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
        <input type="password"  name="password" placeholder="Contraseña" required />
        <i class="fa fa-key"></i>
               
        <button>
          <i class="spinner"></i>
          <span class="state">INICIAR SESIÓN</span>
        </button>
        </form>
        </div><!-- COL 3 -->
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>


        </div><!-- ROW -->
    </div><!-- CONTAINER -->
```

Comment: what is your question

Comment: I assume you want to know how to do this? Make a JS function that is associated with the submit button. Grab the value for password and username, authenticate them against valid credentials. If it works then proceed, otherwise don't.

Answer (score 0):

The user will *always* be redirected when using a html form submission.  The only way to check if the credentials are correct before redirecting the user is to submit the form data using JavaScript (xhr, ajax, or fetch).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
  $("#your-submit-button").click(function(){
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST', 
        url: 'youriP', 
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $('#yourForm').serialize(),
        success: function (x) {                
          // Code to redirect
        },
      });
      return false;
    });
```

Comment: So if i want to do this i need to create a javascript form so with this code will do what i want? 
I am already put this and change it but dont work yet. =(